# Delphi XE2: Debug a 64 bit dll through a 64 bit app

Tags: delphi, debugging, dll, 64-bit, delphi-xe2

Has anyone had success in debugging a 64 bit dll by running/attaching to a 64 bit application? I have Delphi code for both the application and the dll. I can debug the application in 32 bit and 64 bits. I can also debug the 32 bit dll by using <kbd>Run</kbd> -> <kbd>Parameters</kbd> to select the 32 bit version of the app.

However, I cannot appear to debug my 64 bit dll by running the 64 bit app, has anyone got this to work?

Comment: Yes. Debugging 64 bit DLLs works here. Are you using the platform assistant?

Comment: I'm not using the platform assistant, just the RAD Studio XE2 IDE with the dll project open and the exe built in 64 bits. Run -> Parameters in the dll project points to the 64 bit exe, I run the code and any breakpoints have the red 'x' indicating that the debugger will not break as intended.

Comment: Further to this, I have created a new exe project and a new dll project (both in XE2) and built them both in 64 bits and can now debug it. It seems the error is linked to upgrading the project from Delphi 2006. I've had a look through all the project -> options but can't see anything different from the new project.

Comment: Steve, there is a bug in XE2 with 64bit debugging when using an converted dproj file. See http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=100309. This should be fixed in Update 2, but haven't tested it yet.

Comment: I don't know whether this was fixed in Update 2 but it does now work in Update 3. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @evdkraan's answer

"Steve, there is a bug in XE2 with 64bit debugging when using an converted dproj file. See http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=100309. This should be fixed in Update 2, but haven't tested it yet"

"I don't know whether this was fixed in Update 2 but it does now work in Update 3."

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).