# how to debug a 64 bit dll registration process made with regsvr32.exe?

Tags: delphi, debugging, dll, delphi-xe2, regsvr32

i have

> Run time Error 216 at ADDRESS

when registering a 64 bit dll built with Delphi XE2 (I have Update 3).

from command prompt I do (note: system32 folder contains the 64bit exe!)

```
c:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe My64bitdll.dll
```

and after a "dll succesfully installed message"
i have the runtime error.

I would like to debug the registering process, somehow using Run/Parameters/host.

Could anyone post the correct procedure? In some other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067211/delphi-xe2-debug-a-64-bit-dll-through-a-64-bit-app) a bug is mentioned, but it [seems fixed now](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=100309), i have a delphi build older than this one.

**Update:**
Also any comment on the RunTime error is welcome.

Comment: 216 is an Access Violation in an initialization section before SysUtils has been initialized, 217 is the same in a finalization section after SysUtils has been finalized.

Comment: @Marjan You are right about 216. But not about 217. Take a look in System.pas. 217 is `reControlBreak`. And `MapToRunError` maps `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT`, aka `C000013A` onto `reControlBreak`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: thanks for checking. I was kinda sure I had seen 217 produced by AV'ing code, albeit in D5. Actually, it is still possible to get a 217 on an AV after finalization of SysUtils, as 217 is used (hardcodedly) within `_UnhandledException` the under `TABLE_BASED_EXCEPTIONS` conditional define. That is in XE2. Older versions may have used 217 in more circumstances. And indeed in D2006it is used (hardcodedly) in a `_ExceptionHandler`, suggesting 217 may have been reported for any ol' exception.

Comment: @MarjanVenema You get 217 for an unhandled exception in both stack based exceptions (32 bit) and table based exceptions (64 bit). In 32 bit that comes about in `_ExceptionHandler` if `ExceptProc` is `nil`. And there's similar code for 64 bit. So actually, any exception late on in shutdown, after `DoneExceptions` is called results in 217. So I guess that means that your comment is accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Load the DLL project.
2. Modify run parameters (**Run** | **Parameters**) to specify host app as regsvr32. Note that you may need to use C:\Windows\sysnative path to defeat the 32 bit file system redirector.
3. Include path to DLL as command line arguments.
4. Perhaps enable Debug DCUs, in case the error is raised in the Delphi COM self-registration code.

[image]

Then debug the DLL like any other DLL.

Runtime error 216 is an access violation.

Answer (score 1):

1) this runtime error may be just program exit. For example would you debug internals of DllMain, you can easily get past exit point and try to trace ended DLL, which would through RE. Process exit is not looking just like return from subroutine - but rather as a call to special system API function. But debugger does not understand it and continues to trace now dead project.

2) i see not point in using RegSvr32.exe or TRegSvr.exe for debuging. All RegSvr32 does is calling predefined function from DLL. Do you debug your DLL or RegSvr32 itself ?

2.1) If latter - i heard there are sources of RegSvr32, and probably there are debug symbols, but some Microsoft  debugger to be used.

2.2) If former, then there should be now difference how to call those functions and you only have to debug those functions. Just take any code from [File not found when registering DLL with TFileRun and regsvr32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123261) and use it as host.

Comment: You use `regsvr32` as the DLL host to get something to load your DLL and call the appropriate function. You can do it another way, but it's probably quickest to do it that way. Why would using a different host make things simpler? It's pretty obvious that regsvr32 doesn't need debugging, so 2.1 can be scrubbed.

Comment: Yes, that would make thing simpler - yow would have debug info for your program and would be able to determine exact moment of returning from DLL and stopping there, not running all the host through until RunTime Error.

*Hopefully You'd even be able to debug it like EXE calling DLL, not like DLL called by blackbox EXE*